# How to add an image to a sqlite ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite

so far i have an android app which can save data (Simple text) into a sqlite database and display it in to a list view. I would like to be able to add images as well but i dont know how.

here is the class which creates the rows everytime i add some text:

public class TestDatabaseActivity extends ListActivity {
      private CommentsDataSource datasource;

int holanumero;

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_database);

    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

    // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

     final ListView listadeutiles = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // 
    listadeutiles.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {

            holanumero = position;
    }});


  }

  // Will be called via the onClick attribute
  // of the buttons in main.xml
  public void onClick(View view) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
    Comment comment = null;

    switch (view.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.add:

        EditText texto1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String palabra1 = texto1.getText().toString();

        EditText texto2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String palabra2 = texto2.getText().toString();

        String palabra3 = palabra1 + palabra2;

      comment = datasource.createComment(palabra3);
      adapter.add(comment);
      texto1.setText("");
      texto2.setText("");

      break;

    case R.id.delete:
      if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
        comment = (Comment) getListAdapter().getItem(holanumero);

        datasource.deleteComment(comment);
        adapter.remove(comment);
      }
      break;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    datasource.open();
    super.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Comment: Use blob for save image to sqlite but I suggest you to don't save images into sqlite, save them on somewhere in SD Card and use from there.

Answer (score 0):

Saving images in the database is rarely I good idea. You should store the file path to the image in the sd card, and then load that image in your `getView()` method in the `ListView`'s adapter.